# Finding the number of solutions to an equation given the derivative

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

[image: question that I was asked]

Today my teacher gave us this question in class to think about at home. I've been through my textbook trying to find a way to answer this but I have no idea how to find the number of solutions to $g(x)=0$ given that I only have the graph of its derivative, $g'$.

Comment: When $x<0$, the slope is negative, and when $0<x$, the slope is positive. What can you conclude from that?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there can possibly be up to $2$ solutions for $g(x) = 0$, as the graph of $g(x)$ is basically of a concave up parabola with a vertex minimum at $x = 0$. Thus, if the critical point of $g'(0) = 0$ occurs where $g(0) \lt 0$, then as $g'(x) \lt 0$ for $x \lt 0$, this means $g(x)$ is decreasing for $x \lt 0$ and, thus, it could cross from above to below the $x$ axis somewhere in $(a,0)$. Similarly, as $g'(x) \gt 0$ for $x \gt 0$, this means $g(x)$ is increasing for $x \gt 0$ and, as such, it could cross from below to above the $x$ axis somewhere in $(0,b)$.

However, if $g(0) = 0$, then there will be only $1$ zero, and if $g(0) \gt 0$, there will only be no zeros.

As there are no other critical points, with $g(x)$ strictly monotonically decreasing for $x \in [a,0)$, and strictly monotonically increasing for $x \in (0,b]$, there can be no more than $2$ points where $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $0,1$ or $2$ zeros for $g$.

Consider for instance $g(x)=x^2$.  It has $1$ zero.

Or $g(x)=x^2+1$. It has none.

Or $g(x)=x^2-1$. It has two.

We could also subtract a large enough constant $c$ so that $g(x)=x^2-c$ has no zeroes on $[a,b]$.

$g$ will resemble one of these on $[a,b]$.